# Gradle: Replace source file with resource in WAR creation

Tags: gradle, war

In my Gradle WAR build, I'm trying to replace two .js files with newer versions from a external resource.

If files are newer, I want to replace my "base" files in JS folder:

```
task downloadJs {
    ant.mkdir(dir:"${buildDir}/js/")
    ant.get(src:'http://external.url/js/file1.js', dest:"${buildDir}/js/file1.js", usetimestamp: true, ignoreerrors: true)
    ant.get(src:'http://external.url/js/file2.js', dest:"${buildDir}/js/file2.js", usetimestamp: true, ignoreerrors: true)
}

war {
    dependsOn donwloadJs

    from("${buildDir}/js") { 
        include '*' 
        into('js') 
    }
}
```

But this configuration creates duplicates .js files in the war.
I don't want to delete the original files, to avoid having no files if the download fails.

How could I tell the war copy configuration to override files?
`duplicatesStrategy` doesn't seem to work, it allows me to fail or leave duplicates, but no to override.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I myself found a way:

```
war {
    dependsOn downloadJs

    from("${buildDir}/js") { 
        include '*' 
        into('js') 
    }

    exclude {
        it.path.startsWith("js") && file("${buildDir}/js/${it.name}").exists()
    } 
}
```

The key is to let the addition copy the new files, and by other rule, exclude the originals, but only the ones that have been downloaded, checking that the same file exists in the replacing folder

Someone with a cleaner way?